# Integrating a multivariable function one variable at a time

Tags: matlab

I have a function which depends on x and y, f(x,y) (returns a scalar) and I need to integrate it so that for a particular point (x0,y0), I get a function p(theta), I basically convert it to polar, change the origin and integrate over r, so the remaining function only depends on theta:

```
%fun = @(x,y) Some function
fun = @(x,y) fun(x+x0,y+y0);
polarfun = @(r,theta) fun(r.*cos(theta),r.*sin(theta)).*r;
p = @(theta) integral(@(r)polarfun(r,theta),0,Inf);
```

After I get this function, I need to integrate it again (w.r.t theta). This doesn't work (a and b are the limits of the integral)

```
value = integral(p,a,b);
```

I need to set ArrayValued = true for it to work

```
value = integral(p,a,b,'ArrayValued',true);
```

I don't understand why I need to specify it's an ArrayValued function when it's not meant to be, also the integral takes much more time, and I need it to be calculated as fast as possible. Can you explain me why it is ArrayValued, and whether there is a way to make it without the ArrayValued set to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why

There are two levels as to why the `ArrayValued` parameter is required to be set `true`: function requirements and why the function has those requirements.

The requirement of the integrand function handle `fun` per [its documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html#input_argument_fun) is:

> For scalar-valued problems, the function `y = fun(x)` must accept a vector argument, `x`, and return a vector result,`y`. ...  If you set the `'ArrayValued'` option to `true`, then fun must accept a scalar and return an array of fixed size.

Per your code, the function handle `p` receives a vector of integration points via `integral` if `ArrayValued` is not set to `true`.  Then, `polarfun` receives a vector of `theta` and `integral(@(r)polarfun(r,theta),0,Inf)` will produce a scalar value assuming no dimension mismatch happens while that inner-`integral` executes.  And since the outer-`integral` passed a vector and received a scalar back, an error is thrown since those sizes don't match and `ArrayValued` is `false` by default.

Now, why are the requirements the way they are?  Cleve Moler recently wrote a [blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2016/05/23/modernization-of-numerical-integration-from-quad-to-integral/) discussing `integral` and its predecessors.  The long-and-short is that for scalar integrands, vectorized function evaluations yield [the best performance](http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2016/05/23/modernization-of-numerical-integration-from-quad-to-integral/#8f394fe9-1306-4888-ba9c-a2d792dad285) in Matlab; thus, it is used by default.

If the Mathworks wanted to, they could probably write a more sophisticated mechanism for carrying out the evaluation with vector-valued integrands through the use of `bsxfun` or a similar utility. However, the added complexity and subsequent required specific input requirements would more than likely be too burdensome for potentially little, if any, performance increase.  So they assume an inherently scalar function that is Matlab vectorized with an option to fallback to scalar node evaluation.  Additionally, your use-case showcases a huge problem since `polarfun` possesses a fixed vector of `theta` that will more than likely generate a dimension mismatch or give an outright wrong result if `integral` needs to refine its `r` integration at all.

### Recommendation

With all of that being written, I think it's best to just use [`integral2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html) and let Matlab handle everything:

```
fun      = @(x,y) fun(x+x0,y+y0);
polarfun = @(r,theta) fun(r.*cos(theta),r.*sin(theta)).*r;
value    = integral(polarfun,0,Inf,a,b);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know I could just forget about the ArrayValued part (which I did not really understand) and just integrate the 2 variables using integral2. The problem is that I need the integrals to run quick, and performance is naturally much quicker if the function is not an ArrayValued function.

Comment: So at this point I'm not sure what to do, because it takes an excessive amount of time. I could also sample the function and just use quad or trapz, but I would want to have a function because afterwards I need to find a minimum by using a minimization function like fmincon